# Is it possible to populate lookup field using Workflow or Process builder?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

Is is possible to populate lookup field using Workflow or Process builder? I want to populate the lookup field based on the value of another field which is not lookup.

Comment: What kind of data does this other field hold?

Comment: Hi @AdrianLarson, this other field is a text field which will be same as Lookup object records "Name" field value.

Comment: If you are using data loader that is standard functionality. You need to clarify expected behavior when there are multiple matches or no matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use a headless Flow triggered by the Process Builder as in a Flow you can assign a text string to a picklist or as I have done with 2 picklists on different objects where I have used a variable to take the value from one to copy it to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Process builder to update lookup fields 
The Action to set new fields should be of type Reference.

**Example:**
Field: Case [a lookup to case on customObject customObject__c]

Type: Reference

Value: the field on customObject

Comment: Hi @Shruthi,thanks for your reply. I tried with Process builder but you can select only lookup field as value. I want to select lookup record based on non lookup field value.

Comment: I am afraid you can solve this only via code. Either use before trigger or apex invocable method in process builder.